# Xcode version 14 In-App Purchase capability not available

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build, in-app-purchase

I have a Unity-based game with in-app purchasing that is operational in Android using Admob. I have now built an iOS target. Building under Xcode version 14 the link has many undefined variables. I realize that the target app needs to have the in-app purchase capability added. But under the signing and capabilities tab in Xcode, when I hit the + to select a capability to add, in-app purchase is not a capability I can include.

I have gone to the App Store Connect and selected in-app purchases for my app. I have created a consumable Product ID for my in-app purchase. I have also created a Key file for the in-app purchase. However, Xcode does not seem to recognize that I have created an in-app product ID and is not enabling me to include the in-app purchase capability in Xcode.

On the Xcode signing and capabilities page, just below the signing section is an icon that appears as a rectangle inside a rectangle followed by the words In-App Purchases. This does not appear to be a check box. But it is recognizing something about the app and in-app purchases. There is a garbage can to the right of this line which implies I can delete that line, but it is unclear what the meaning is for this line on this page.

I read something about signing onto App Store Connect from Xcode but I have no idea how one does that. Is this the step to have Xcode recognize that the in-app purchase capability option should be among the capabilities that can be selected?

I am at a loss to move forward at this point. It would seem unless this capability is added to Xcode, that the library associated with in-app purchases is not being included in the Build. How can I enable the in-app purchase capability so I can complete the build of the Unity game which is working successfully in Android?

Comment: Did you check it on developer.apple.com -> identifiers -> select your app id -> In the Capabilities section, scroll down to see the In-App Purchase line? (It's ticked by default.)

Comment: The in-app purchase capability on that page is greyed out but does have a checkmark on it. I did read on that page, a message that said if any capability is changed you need to create a new provisioning profile. If a new one is created, how is that moved to XCODE or how do you tell XCODE to use that profile?

Comment: That's so weird, idk why it is not ticked. However, provisioning profile can be used in 2 ways. Automatically when you mark `Automatically manage signing` on `Signing & Capabilities` in Xcode. And another way is manually on `Build Setting` -> `Development Team` and `Provisioning Profile`

Comment: I have automatically signing set and that is how I have built my prior versions properly. But this is the first version I have build with In-App Purchases which is intergrating Admob to process them. But again the build fails with undefined references all relarted to a missing In-App Purchases libary.

Comment: Do you have a paid developer account?

Comment: Of course I have a developer account. This is an update to an existing game that has been online for 30+ weeks.